# auto mapper mapping with a struct inside the class

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

have the following objects I need to map although I'm not able to get it working using automapper!  I think its because of the struct but Im not sure how this differs the mapping.

I'm trying to map the objects using the following although failing!  Please help!? Thanks

```
var result = Result(..);  // TYPEOF = B.Result
var temp = Mapper.Map<A.Result, B.ParseResult>(result);
```

The error: "Trying to map Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.."

```
public class A.Result
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<A.MyError> Errors { get; set; }
}

public struct A.MyError
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

## MAP TO

```
[DataContract]
public class B.Result
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<B.MyError> Errors { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public struct B.MyError
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not instructed AutoMapper how to do the conversion between your types. You can fix this by adding `Mapper.CreateMap<AResult, BResult>();` to your code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AResult, BResult>();
var temp = Mapper.Map<AResult, BResult>(result);
```